# Directory.GetFiles string gives an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, getfiles

I am creating a website using asp.net and c#
I need to access all files one by one in a directory. So I wrote the following code.

```
    string[] ssImgs = Directory.GetFiles("images/movies");
    Label1.Text = ssImgs[0];
    Label2.Text = ssImgs[1];
```

But it gives an error. What is the correct way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct way is telling us which error you're receiving ;-)

Comment: The correct way to do this is to fix the error. If you need help doing it, maybe posting the actual error might help.

Comment: Watch out! I can feel that some down-voters are going to jump in here and ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little advice, when using the file system in ASP.NET, leverage `Server.MapPath`:

```
string[] ssImgs = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/movies"));
```

where `~/images/movies` is the full **relative** path from the **root** of the web application.

Secondly, before just grabbing an index of the array, make sure it's actually there. It would be better to change your indexing code to something like this:

```
Label1.Text = ssImgs.Length >= 1 ? ssImgs[0] : "File 1 not found.";
Label2.Text = ssImgs.Length >= 2 ? ssImgs[1] : "File 2 not found.";
```

By making these two changes you won't have to worry about getting a `DirectoryNotFound` exception or an `IndexOutOfRange` exception.

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential issues here.

1. If you doing have `using System.IO;` in your file, the `Directory` class will not be found by the compiler.
2. The way you're specifying your path (`"images/movies"`) will be relative to the current working directory, which is likely not the proper directory.  You should use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or the `Path` class to build a full path to the proper folder, so you can specify the correct folder with a full, absolute path.

Comment: You mean `Server.MapPath`, not `Path` don't you?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, eh, technically you could use the `Path` class and construct a proper path if it were really well known.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Potentially, yes - the Path class might also be useful, depends a lot on where things are...

Comment: I have already added using System.IO;

Comment: @LIH Then it's most likely that you need to get the proper path, not a relative one.

Answer (score 1):

I got the correct way. It is

```
    string[] ssImgs = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("images/movies"));
```

Comment: Not an answer - there is no point to re-post answer. Simply accept correct one.